# HtmlEditorExtendor;Multiline TextBox not returning all the text

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax

I have a multi line textbox control with an HtmlEditorExtender,when i enter the multiple lines of text in the texbox and then click save, its returning only the first line of the textbox instead of all the lines.Please help me on this issue.

```
<asp:textbox id="txtHtmlEditor" textmode="MultiLine" runat="server" width="100%"
                    height="120px" columns="1000" rows="1000" wrap="true" xmlns:asp="#unknown" />
                <asp:htmleditorextender id="txtHtmlEditor_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" enabled="True"
                    targetcontrolid="txtHtmlEditor">
                    <profilebindings>
                    </profilebindings>
                    <toolbar>
                        <asp:Bold />
                        <asp:Italic />
                        <asp:Underline />
                        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
                        <asp:FontNameSelector />
                        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
                        <asp:FontSizeSelector />
                        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
                        <asp:ForeColorSelector />
                        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
                        <asp:RemoveFormat />
                    </toolbar>
                </asp:htmleditorextender>
```

btnSave_OnClick()
{
 returing only first line of the text box value
}

Comment: How do you get the value of the `HtmlEditorExtender`?

Comment: I am getting value from textbox(target control).

Comment: Can you show your `btn_OnClick` code?

Comment: protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var editorType = Request.QueryString["type"];
            var companyId = Request.QueryString["companyId"];        

            switch (editorType)
            {
                case "company":
                  
                    Session.Add(S_COMPANY_NAME_HEADER, txtHtmlEditor.Text);
                    break;
                case "details":
                   
                    Session.Add(S_COMPANY_DETAILS_HEADER,txtHtmlEditor.Text);
                    break;
            }
        }